# Derived class constructor errors

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Trying to explain this very concisely

- I have an **abstract** base class, and 2 derived classes.
- The base class has a constructor that takes in a single string argument and assigns it to a field
- The derived classes constructors call the base class constructor and each take a single string argument.
- These are part of a class library project that is referenced in the main solution.
- In the main, while I attempt to create an instance of the class, passing in a single argument (as should be), I run across this error:

`library.class` does not contain a constructor that takes a single argument.

If I create an object without a parameter the following error line is created:

> `library.class.constructor(string)` is inaccessible due to it's protection level.

I am not able to find a solution to this problem, I am providing my essential code below, if anyone can take a look and gauge what mistake is happening here, that would be really awesome:

#### The base class:

```
abstract class EmployeeBase
    {
private string empNumber;
public EmployeeBase(string CurrentEmployeeNumber)  { empNumber = CurrentEmployeeNumber;}
......
```

#### The derived class:

```
class EmployeeExempt : EmployeeBase
    {
        public EmployeeExempt(string CurrentEmployeeNumber) : base(CurrentEmployeeNumber) 
        { }
........
```

#### The main method:

```
EmployeeExempt emp1 = new EmployeeExempt("1000");
```

This I believe is the core of my program, hopefully somebody can spot out the mistake that is happening here

Comment: Ummm, [what was the total number of C# questions on Stack Overflow (before this one was posted) doing in this question's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5645087/revisions)

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers below as correct?

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly declare both your base class and your derived class as `public`. The [default accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for classes is `internal` so both of these classes are inaccessible from your main method. They are only accessible from within your class library project.

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting *three* error messages:

```
Test.cs(7,9): error CS0122: 'EmployeeExempt' is inaccessible due to its
        protection level
Test.cs(7,35): error CS0122: 'EmployeeExempt' is inaccessible due to its
        protection level
Test.cs(7,31): error CS1729: 'EmployeeExempt' does not contain a constructor
        that takes 1 arguments
```

The first two should make the problem pretty clear - as the other answers have said, EmployeeBase and EmployeeExempt are both internal classes (the default accessibility for non-nested types), which means they're only accessible within the same assembly. The class containing the Main method is in a different assembly, so you don't have access to them.

Just make them public.

I'll admit that the last error message is slightly misleading, but you should have looked at *all* the error messages rather than just that one - the first two should have given you enough hints about what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see, is that `EmployeeExempt` is `internal` and not `public`, but that doesn't match the error message...
I assume, you haven't shown us all relevant code, or the code really is slightly different from what you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your classes are being declared private. Prefix the class names with public or if they are intended to be in the same assembly perhaps internal.

Answer (score -1):

The string in the base class EmployeeBase is private . Try making it public .

Comment: The base class constructor *is* public. The class itself is not, though.

Comment: @Sujay: Your edit with the field being private is still wrong, therefore, I will not remove my downvote.

Comment: @Daniel . No problem "Every mistake you make shows you are still learning" - John Lenon ( While My Guitar Gently Weeps) :-)